# Referencing a library via a VM

Tags: c#, com, adobe-indesign

I'm working on a project to use InDesign from C#. I see that I can reference libraries of InDesign from the C# project. Can I do this where InDesign is hosted in a Virtual Machine? If not, can I add the library and compile without having InDesign installed on the development machine?